# Markdown: Is there a way to specify raw text in markdown?

Tags: python, markdown

I am using python to generated markdown, is there a way to specify a "raw" string in markdown terms?

i.e.

```
<-- magic markdown formatting to indicate not to format the following text
# This is a comment

--- end of text ---
<-- end of magic markdown formatting
```

Should appear as is without letting markdown touch it at all.

Comment: What python module (if any) are you using and what is the flavor of markdown?

Comment: I think the term you should be looking for is `verbatim`.

Comment: I am using this one: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Markdown I am not sure about the flavour :) its my first markdown project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add comments, you could use the syntax for code.

In github flavoured markdown it normally uses ``` (3 backticks)
In the python-markdown it is like Stack overflow, where you put 4 spaces in front of the line.

if you do not want to format it like code, you can simply escape the markdown syntax like :

```
\# comment
```

Will display `# comment` rather than the word "comment" as a heading.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that an extension was needed for the python library to recognise the ``` (3 backticks) but works fine

Comment: The "3 backticks" method (called Fenced Code Blocks) is not standard Markdown and not supported by every Markdown parser (or even in the same way by the ones that do support it). However, the indented code blocks are [standard Markdown behavior](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode) and should be supported everywhere Markdown is supported.